# How to execute a Stored Procedure using a UniqueIdentifier Data type Variable within a cursor? (WSUS/MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have this Cursor in which I have used the Results from a `SELECT` query to retrieve and store the updateID for Driver updates in a Table in the DB. I want to use that Table which I created to run a Stored Procedure against each row, so I have created the below Cursor after some research on how to do so:

```
DECLARE @UpdateID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

DECLARE DriverPurge CURSOR
    For Select UpdateID From dbo.DriversUpdateID

Open DriverPurge
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM DriverPurge
        INTO @UpdateID
        
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            
            exec spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID @UpdateId
            FETCH NEXT FROM DriverPurge
                INTO @UpdateID
        END
Close DriverPurge
Deallocate DriverPurge
```

and the Stored Procedure which I am referencing has the following queries (ignore the ALTER PROCEDURE):

```
USE [SUSDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID]    Script Date: 15/06/2022 15:33:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID]
    @updateID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @localUpdateID INT
SET @localUpdateID = NULL
SELECT @localUpdateID = LocalUpdateID FROM dbo.tbUpdate WHERE UpdateID = @updateID
IF @localUpdateID IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('The update could not be found.', 16, 40)
    RETURN(1)
END
IF EXISTS (SELECT r.RevisionID FROM dbo.tbRevision r
           WHERE r.LocalUpdateID = @localUpdateID
           AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbBundleDependency WHERE BundledRevisionID = r.RevisionID)
               OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbPrerequisiteDependency WHERE PrerequisiteRevisionID = r.RevisionID)))
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('The update cannot be deleted as it is still referenced by other update(s).', 16, 45)
    RETURN(1)
END
DECLARE @retcode INT
EXEC @retcode = dbo.spDeleteUpdate @localUpdateID
IF @@ERROR <> 0 OR @retcode <> 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID got error from spDeleteUpdate', 16, -1)
    RETURN(1)
END
RETURN (0)
```

The cursor itself looks to be executing, however, when I stopped the operation to check on progress, I was greeted to row after row of Error Messages:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spDeleteRevision, Line 33 [Batch Start Line 0]
@errorMessage
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spDeleteUpdate, Line 72 [Batch Start Line 0]
spDeleteUpdate got error from spDeleteRevision
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 0]
spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID got error from spDeleteUpdate
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction or tell me where i may have gone wrong, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: *"I was greeted to row after row of Error Messages:"* And those are the errors you defined in your procedure: `RAISERROR('spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID got error from spDeleteUpdate', 16, -1)` Why are you not `THROW`ing the actual error? The reason you get a useless error is because you dispose of the *actual* error. If you are going to use custom errors, at least make them useful. We have no idea what those errors mean, as we don't know what the actual error that caused your ambiguous error to occur was.

Comment: Those aren't custom errors, they come default with the SUSDB database, @Larnu.

Comment: `spDeleteUpdateByUpdateID got error from spDeleteUpdate` is a custom error... And it'#s meaningless, other than to say "An error occured"; it doesn't tell you *what* that error was.

Comment: Not a custom error set by me. As i stated - those errors came default with the Stored procedures included in the SUSDB database. I have not made any changes to the error actions nor the messages. It's not my fault that it's a completely useless error message that was included by default, jeez.

Comment: If you are posting code, it is presumed you have ownership of it, RyT ; if you don't, then before posting you should be ensuring you can relicense the code under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: There is no belittling here, just explanations of that the errors unhelpful as they hide the true error, and that the procedure should be `THROW`ing the error (so you know what the error is) If you didn't code the statements, how were we to know that (you didn't state so)? If you truly believe my comments are belittlement, flag them as rude. Though if you feel that explanation isn't constructive, then you may find things hard here...

Comment: You can give an explanation and still belittle someone, they are not exclusive to each other. All you had to say was "Those are custom errors which are referencing errors in another procedure, so they aren't very helpful. You could try `THROW` ing the error -give an example-" but that isnt what you did. It's very belittling the way in which you spoke down to me, i'm just calling you out for it. No harm done, just didn't sit well with me.

Answer (score 0):

As always with cursors, they are slow, and nearly always not necessary.

You can do this as one big joined delete. To ensure consistency, use a transaction and the `UPDLOCK` hint when checking with `IF EXISTS`. The `UPDLOCK` is only for the table being modified.

> Use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`, as that respects transactions better. Use `XACT_ABORT` to ensure rollback in case of error.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;  -- always use XACT_ABORT when using transactions

BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT du.UpdateID
    FROM dbo.DriversUpdateID du

    EXCEPT

    SELECT u.LocalUpdateID
    FROM dbo.tbUpdate u WITH (UPDLOCK)
)
BEGIN
    THROW 'The update could not be found.', 50001, 40;
END;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.DriversUpdateID du
    JOIN dbo.tbUpdate u WITH (UPDLOCK)
        ON u.LocalUpdateID = du.UpdateID
    JOIN dbo.tbRevision r
        ON r.LocalUpdateID = u.LocalUpdateID
    WHERE (
        EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.tbBundleDependency bd
            WHERE bd.BundledRevisionID = r.RevisionID
        )
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.tbPrerequisiteDependency pd
            WHERE pd.PrerequisiteRevisionID = r.RevisionID
           )
    )
)
BEGIN
    THROW 'The update cannot be deleted as it is still referenced by other update(s).', 50001, 45;
END;

DELETE u
FROM dbo.DriversUpdateID du
JOIN dbo.tbUpdate u
    ON u.LocalUpdateID = du.UpdateID;

COMMIT;
```

If you don't want to bother with any of that error checking, you can just use a single joined delete. There is no need for a transaction on a single statement.

```sql
DELETE u
FROM dbo.DriversUpdateID du
JOIN dbo.tbUpdate u
    ON u.LocalUpdateID = du.UpdateID;
```

Comment: It's simply a joined delete. Think of the equivalent `SELECT`, then simply delete all the `tbUpdate` rows that come out of the join

Comment: Thanks, @Charlieface . I've been trying to figure out the most efficient way to accomplish this for some weeks now on-and-off, but i haven't had the SQL knowledge to understand a lot of what I've read so your response is really helpful! The only thing i'm struggling with is understanding the logic of this snippet
`
DELETE u
FROM dbo.DriversUpdateID du
JOIN dbo.tbUpdate u
    ON u.LocalUpdateID = du.UpdateID;
`
Does this delete entries in the child tables as well, such as 'tbRevision'? I can see them in the error checking; or will i need to add a `DELETE` for each table?

Comment: reposted above comment cause ran out of editing time - apologies!

Comment: No in SQL Server you can only delete from one table at a time, the one immediately after the word `DELETE`, in this case from the one aliased `u` which is `tbUpdate`

Comment: Okay, got it. I'll take this and run with it - i did see something about a cascading ` DELETE ` function, however i don't believe that is enabled in my environment, though i may be able to add/modify some Keys in the DB to enable this. Thanks again for the help!